# file_exists() showing opposite results than expected

Tags: php, file-exists

I have a very, very simple function:

```
function getUserImage($id) {

    if (file_exists(SITE_ROOT . '/images/' . $id)) {
        return "http://www.---.net/images/" . $id;                         
    } else {
        return "http://www.---.net/images/usericon.png";  
    }
}
```

It is being called this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo getUserImage($row['user_id'].".jpg"); ?>" />
```

What I am trying to do is show a default icon if the user does not have a profile picture.    It is showing the default icon every time even though the correct path is being tested (I have confirmed this).  Maybe I am using `file_exists()` wrong?

Comment: What is `SITE_ROOT`? A **URL** to your site root, or a **local file system path**?

Comment: I think the physical path to the file is not correct you should check that.

Comment: what do you get if you echo `SITE_ROOT . 'images/' . $id`

Comment: Maybe you need to use this : SITE_ROOT . '/images/' . $id

Comment: my SITE_ROOT is what it sounds like.  It is not the URL but the directory structure on the web server.

Comment: @Orangepill I get the absolute path

Comment: @KickingLettuce does this one fail as well?

Comment: Guys I am an idiot.  I have two different folders.  `profile_pics` with the user images, and `images` where I keep site  elements, icons, etc.  I was checking if the file exited in the WRONG directory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getUserImage($id) {

    if (file_exists(SITE_ROOT . '/profile_pics/' . $id)) {
        return "http://www.---.net/profile_pics/" . $id;                         
    } else {
        return "http://www.---.net/images/usericon.png";  
    }


}
```

I was searching in the wrong folder. It should have been `profile_pics` all along~

Answer (score 0):

file_exists() works at the filesystem level. You're passing in something like `/images/whatever`, so it'll be looking for a `whatever` file in an `images` directory that is at the TOP of the file system, e.g. you're trying to for the equivalent of

```
c:\images\whatever
```

instead of where the image actually exists, in your site's document root, e.g.

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\html\images\whatever
```

You generally can NOT use a  url directly in a file-system context, because the paths you see in a URL very rarely EVER directly map to what's on the server's file system.